# Path3D not Tilting in Godot 4

Tags: mesh, godot, godot4

I am making a racing game and I want to tilt the track on it's roll axis, but when I change the roll value, the track mesh does not actually tilt. I am using CSGPolygon3Ds for the track. The visual of the Path3D node shows that the track tilts to the side, but the mesh does not do the same.

[In this image the track is tilted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39gMX.png)
[Here I set the tilt to 1, with 0 being no tilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYyE.png)
[The visual track does not tilt with the Path3D point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSriY.png)

I tried setting the tilt to 1, but the track did not update and tilt. I am pretty sure the tilt value is supposed to tilt the track because you can visually see the track tilt when I change the tilt value. I don't know what else I was supposed to do, except for messing around with the CSGPolygon3D values, hoping that would do something. The image below shows what the current values are.

[These are the settings for the CSGPolygon3Ds. There might be something wrong here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSxLQ.png)